# Angular 6 event.stopPropagation() not working in directive (template-driven form takes event.data already)

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

I am trying to make a citizenNumber component to use in forms. It implements ControlValueAccessor for ngModel.

```ts
export class CitizenNumberComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _value: string;
    @Input() placeholder = '';
    @Input() required = true;

    get value(): string {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: string) {
        this._value = value;
        this.propagateChange(value);
    }

    // registers 'fn' that will be fired when changes are made
    // this is how we emit the changes back to the form
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    // not used, used for touch input
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { }

    // this is the initial value set to the component
    writeValue(value: string): void {
        if (value) {
        this._value = value;
        }
    }

    // the method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
    propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
    }
```

I make a NumberDirective to restrict input except 0-9 digits.

In numberDirective I used 'input' event because keypress, keydown and keyup not working android chrome.

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input[jhiNumbersOnly]'
})
export class NumberDirective {
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Delete', 'Insert', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowLeft'];

    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event) {
        const key = event['data'];
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        const initalValue = event.target['value'];
        event.target['value'] = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
        if (initalValue !== event.target['value']) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, everything works but altough event has stopped, the model takes the value.**

As an example, my input maxlength is 11. after 10 number enter, if some key entered (except 0-9) form will be validate.

Look component in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-citizen-number);

**Can you help me with my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your `input` handler by a `keydown` handler. Then if the key is good, do nothing, otherwise, prevent the event from happening.

The problem is that if you listen to the input event, it will be too late, the `ngModel` will have been updated, so you have to listen to the `keydown` event and filter it appropriately.

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(e.key) !== -1 || new RegExp(/[0-9]/g).test(e.key)) {
      return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I tested this code in your stackblitz demo and it works.

**EDIT**: You mentionned you cannot use the keydown handler, sorry.

I managed to get it to work with the `oninput` handler on the the `<input>` element and I removed your directive on the input:

```
<div class = "form-group">
  <label class = "form-control-label label-color" for = "citizenNumber">Citizen Number
  </label>
  <input type = "text" 
          class = "form-control input-css" 
          name = "citizenNumber"
          id = "citizenNumber"
          #citizenNumber="ngModel"
          oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');"
          [(ngModel)] = "value"
          [placeholder] = "placeholder"
          minlength = "11"
          maxlength = "11"
          [required] = "required">
  <div *ngIf = "citizenNumber.invalid && (citizenNumber.dirty || citizenNumber.touched)"
      class = "form-text text-danger">
      <small *ngIf = "citizenNumber.errors.required">This field is required.</small>
      <small *ngIf = "citizenNumber.errors.minlength">This field must be 11 characters.</small>
      <small *ngIf = "citizenNumber.errors.invalidTc">This is not a citizen number</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here is an updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-citizen-number-filtering).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also tried keydown and I know it works. As my question **keypress, keydown and keyup not working** on **android** chrome. Since it is a web site, it is generaly used on mobile

Comment: Ok I will have a look, by doing some filtering in your value setter, it seems to work well in your stackblitz

Comment: **String.replace** works **one** time. So press more than one time the value will enter.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, by filtering like this, I am not able to enter any letter, string.replace will be called every time the setter is called, that is to say every time you enter a letter, it also works if you paste a string with letters in it. I added an updated stackblitz, do you have errors with it?

Comment: The problem is form where i use citizen-number-component. If you look app.component html, parent form will be **valid** when you enter **a string value** after **10 numbers** enter although **ngModel not change**.

Comment: Ok, I see, I think I got it to work by replaceing the directive with a javascript `oninput` handler directly on the input. I updated the answer and the Stackblitz as well.

Comment: **I really appreciate for your help. It seems to work mobile also** :). Thank you very much.